# Logaritmic equation

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

Solve the system of equations

> $20=x(1-e^{-k})$
>
> $30=x(1-e^{-2k})$

Can anybody explain how to find $k$ and $x$ from this 2 equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide one by another one, then cross-multiply and you get
$2(1-e^{-2k})=3(1-e^{-k})$.  That is a quadratic equation.

Comment: it would be better if you can type more latex (specially if you say "divide one by another one") :)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac32=\frac{x(1-e^{-2k})}{x(1-e^{-k})}=\frac{1-(e^{-k})^2}{1-e^{-k}}$.